# Casting required for the generic

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have the class:

```
class ColumnBuilder < C extends ICompositeColumn > implements IColumnBuilder < C , 
List < ColumnNameComponent > > {

    @Override
    public C getColumn(List<ColumnNameComponent> columnNameComponents) {
        Collections.sort(columnNameComponents);
        C compositeColumn = (C)new CompositeColumnImpl();

        for (ColumnNameComponent component : columnNameComponents){
            compositeColumn.add(component.getOrdinal(),component.getValue());
        }
        return  compositeColumn;
    }
```

Class CompositeColumnImpl implements ICompositeColumn  interface
So why the compiler requires put cassting in this line:

```
C compositeColumn = (C)new CompositeColumnImpl();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Because you declared `C extends ICompositeColumn`. This means that every type that extends `ICompositeColumn` can be bound to `C` and your type `CompositeColumnImpl` is only one of them.

Think about this subclass

```
public class SubColumnBuilder extends ColumnBuilder<AnotherCompositeColumnImpl> {
}

public class AnotherCompositeColumnImpl implements ICompositeColumn{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume the compiler can't know if `C` is equal or super of `CompositeColumnImpl`, it probably only knows that they both implement the interface.

Therefore, the cast is necessary.

If your return type was `ICompositeColumn`, it would work without cast.

Answer (score 0):

`C` can be any type that implements `ICompositeColumn`, not only `CompositeColumnImpl`. By casting to `C`, you're not casting to `ICompositeColumn`. So it cannot be an implicit cast, as it's not an upcast.

Answer (score 0):

`C` could be different type than `CompositeColumnImpl`.

It can be any class that implements `ICompositeColumn`, for example `SomeOtherCompositeColumnImpl`